# How to set order of operations for Field Calculation in Network Analyst Evaluator Dialogue?

Tags: routing, field-calculator, network-analyst, arcgis-desktop

I desire to have a ratio calculated each time I create a new route.

To get this ratio, I created and populated a field that multiplied the length of each segment by a designated number from 1-5, where 1 was most desirable, we'll call this [FieldValue]. Theoretically, when divided by the length, this would produce a value that, the closer to 1 would indicate a more desirable route.

In the **[field evaluator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000021000000)** value dialogue box, I was able to divide my calculated value by the length of the segment ([FieldValue]/[Length]). I was hoping that they would sum each field first and then divide the two values at the end.

However, when I ran the route analysis, the values were dividing each row, and summing all of the individually divided values at the end.

I would like each field, [FieldValue] and [Length] to sum first, then divide the two summed fields to produce the ratio. It would appear that I can do this with a VB script or Prelogic within the network analyst evaluator value field, but I lack the programming skills to do so.

What would be the best route to take in order to have them calculate in my desired order?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using to try and do this?  Is using Python rather than VBScript an option for you?  Please edit your Question to revise it with these clarifications and anything else you think relevant that may have come to light since you asked this Question over three years ago.